# Run ExecutorService tasks continuously

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

I want to use method `newWorkStealingPool()` to get thread and run them continuously every 1 `sec`. Using the following sample code :

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        Runnable task = () -> System.out.println("Scheduling: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

        int initialDelay = 0;
        int period = 1;
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, period, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I can run task continuously but I want to use the method `newWorkStealingPool()` to get threads. Using the following code:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = (ScheduledExecutorService)Executors.newWorkStealingPool();

        Runnable task = () -> System.out.println("Scheduling: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

        int initialDelay = 0;
        int period = 1;
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, period, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I got the error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService
```

Using `ExecutorService` object it's possible to use `newWorkStealingPool()` but I don't know if is there any way to run `ExecutorService` object continuously like what object `ScheduledExecutorService` provides?

Comment: What is your requirement other than "I want to use method `newWorkStealingPool()`", which isn't a requirement? Smells like homework

Comment: It's because `newWorkStealingPool` use idle thread from other finished task and improves performance.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar in addition I don't want to set number of threads manually.

Comment: I know what `newWorkStealingPool` does, that wasn't my question. Let me rephrase it in a more lucid way - what are you trying to achieve in this code? What is the problem you're trying to solve? Update your question accordingly, don't post in comments.

Comment: I want to achieve: 1- using threads(ExecutionService) to do some computation continuously with period 1 sec. 2- use `newWorkStealingPool` strategy to get threads. Understandable?

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be achieved with creating `ScheduledExecutorService` and `ForkJoinPool`. `ScheduledExecutorService` will be used to submit tasks to `ForkJoinPool` at specified intervals. And `ForkJoinPool` will execute these tasks.

```
    ForkJoinPool executor = (ForkJoinPool) Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
    // this will be only used for submitting tasks, so one thread is enough
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    Runnable task = () -> System.out.println("Scheduling: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    int initialDelay = 0;
    int period = 1;
    scheduledExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(()->executor.submit(task), initialDelay, period, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Executors.newWorkStealingPool()` produces a [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html). The **ForkJoinPool** class does not implement the [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) interface so you cannot cast it to a **ScheduledExecutorService**.

Furthermore the **ForkJoinPool** and **ScheduledExecutorService** are fundamentally different thread pools. If you need to schedule a task to execute once every second stick with a **ScheduledExecutorService**, since it is suitable for your use case. **ForkJoinPools** are intended to use in cases where you have many small units of work divided among many threads, not for when you want to regularly execute something.